# Error when using command line to run formatting USB drive in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, command-line, command-line-arguments

all. I am new mac developer. I would like to format the USB drive in using command line in objective-c. Here is some code, and it will give me error when I run it.

```
 NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/env"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"diskutil", @"eraseVolume",@"MS-DOS",@"PK", @"\"/Volumes/PK/\"", nil]];
....
```

Here is the error:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/sbin/diskutil) has __RESTRICT/__restrict section
Unable to find disk for "/Volumes/PK/"
```

But when I type this line in terminal it works fine. I have no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. The problem is the path. I should get rid of " "

Answer (score 1):

Check this code. It's working fine.

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/env"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"diskutil", @"eraseVolume", @"exfat", @"name of pd", @"path of pd",nil]];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```